# Definir atributo como chave estrangeira ebean intellij

Tags: banco-de-dados, play-framework, intellij-idea

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
    @Entity
public class exemplo extends Model {

    @Id
    private Integer id_nome;
    private String Designacao_PT;
    private String Nota_PT;

    public exemplo(Integer id_nome,String Designacao_PT,String Nota_PT){

        this.id_nome= id_nome;
        this.Designacao_PT = Designacao_PT;
        this.Nota_PT = Nota_PT;
    }
}
```

Desta forma a chave primária fica a 'id_nome'. Se eu quiser colocar a Designacao_PT como chave estrangeira como posso fazer?

Já vi qualquer coisa sobre o @joinColumn mas ainda não percebi bem. Estou a programar no IntelliJ 14.0.2